# Jest: Testing Async Function

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to test an async function using Jest, but my mock doesn't seem to want to resolve a Promise.

workflow.test.js

```
jest.mock("../../test/__mocks__/workflow");
import {list} from "../../test/__mocks__/workflow"

describe("workflow list api function", () => {
    it("should get a list of workflows", async () => {
        const expectedListData = {
            message: "Successfully retrieved workflow list!",
            data: [
                {
                    id: "123",
                },
            ]
        };
        const listData = await list();

        expect(listData.message).not.toBeNull();
        expect(listData.message).toBe(expectedListData.message);
        expect(listData.data).toBe(expectedListData.data)
    });
});
```

**mock**/workflow

```
import { listData } from "./data";

export const list = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = listData;

        if (data) {
            resolve(data)
        } else {
            reject({
                error: "List not found..."
            })
        }
    });
};
```

I keep getting an error saying "listData.message is undefined" and when I log the "listData" variable it is also undefined even though the Promise in my "workflow.test.js" file should be resolving a list of data.

This is my first time ever trying to run some tests and I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've looked a lot of places trying to get this to work, but everything I've tried hasn't been working. Just hoping to get some pointers, because I'm not sure what else to try at this point.

Comment: I see that you're mocking workflow at the top of your test file. Why are you mocking that? It seems like you're mocking what you're trying to test. Try removing that mock.

Comment: Thank you so much Chaz, that was it! I'll have to go back and look at my example and see if I misinterpreted or if the example I was looking at was wrong as well.